# jquery fadein effect not working onclick

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am having issues getting a fadeIn to work with my jquery.  Was hoping someone could help.
Basically, I have a button that I click on my page that will essentially pull in the next set of results (code below).  I'd like to add the fadein effect when the results are returned to the screen, however I am doing something wrong.
Below are examples I tried, but are not working.

**example 1**

```
var number = 0;
$(function(){
  $('#showMore').click(function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
    number++;

    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "/getnext.php",
       data: {"count":number},

       success: function(results){
        $('#results').html(results);
        $('#results').fadeIn()


       }
     });

  });

});
```

**example 2**

```
var number = 0;
$(function(){
  $('#showMore').click(function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
    number++;

    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "/getnext.php",
       data: {"count":number},

       success: function(results){
        $('#results').fadeIn().html(results);


       }
     });

  });

});
```

Any thoughts on why this is not working?

Comment: `$('#results').hide().fadeIn()` ??? Basically, to get fadeIn() effect to work, element must be hidden

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure there is an response first :

```
$('#results').html(results).hide().fadeIn();
```

Answer (score 0):

A. Wolff is correct that the element must be hidden in order to use .fidein() on it. The first example is also missing the ";" semicolon at the end of the .fadein function.